# ¿Cómo puedo identificar la causa del alto consumo de memoria RAM en mi aplicación Spring Boot después de descargar un reporte en Excel?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo una aplicación en Spring Boot que crea archivos de Excel con reportes. Sin embargo, he notado que después de generar los reportes, la aplicación sigue consumiendo memoria RAM. No estoy seguro de la causa, así que estoy usando una herramienta llamada JConsole para monitorear el uso de la memoria RAM.

**este es el controlador**

```
   @GetMapping("/reporte-prueba")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getPrueba() {
       InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(reportePrueba.servicePrueba());
       return ResponseEntity.ok()
                   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, CSV_HEADER)
                   .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(CSV_MEDIA_TYPE))
                   .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
                   .body(file);
```

**Nota**:He implementado el método para generar el archivo Excel y me he asegurado de que todas las conexiones se cierren correctamente